# %npm_package_name% is undefined when starting an ASP.NET Core / Angular app

Tags: asp.net-core, npm, angular-cli, visual-studio-2022

I created a new app using the Standalone Angular Typescript project template. When I run the app, I get errors about the PEM file. The app is started by this line in `package.json`:

```
ng serve --ssl --ssl-cert %appdata%\asp.net\https\%npm_package_name%.pem 
               --ssl-key %APPDATA%\\ASP.NET\\https\\%npm_package_name%.key
```

When I replaced the two paths with the actual full path, it worked.

When I did echo `%npm_package_name%` I got `%npm_package_name%` instead of the actual value so this tells me it couldn't find the path.

How can I get %npm_package_name% to be defined and have the correct package name value? package.json has

```
"name": "health-check"
```

and I assume that's where `%npm_package_name%` should be getting its value?